# Meteor - Accessing DOM elements from another template events handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Good Afternoon everyone.

I'm trying to color the comment item when I go to the page with the comment included through notifications. - Like fb or stack overflow.

I have everything working except the part that I mentioned above.

**Notification Events**

```
Template.notification.events({
    'click a':function() {
        var commentTemplate = this.commentId;
        console.log(commentTemplate);    //Target commentId returns successfully

        //Code here needed 
        //to color comment when page moves to
        //coresponding page.
   }
```

**Template.commentList**

```
//HTML
{{#each comments}}
    {{> commentItem}}
{{/each}}

//JS
comments: function(){
    return Comments.find({postId:this._id});
}
```

I've also tried grabbing the corresponding commentItem's id through `console.log` using `this._id`.

So What I would like to know is,

is there a way to link `this.commentId` from notifications and access `<template name = "commentItem">` with corresponding `_id`. And then manipulate it's `element` / `dom` by using things such as `.addClass`.

Please nudge me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, when you click a link in the notifications template, you want to take the user to the commentList page and then manipulate the CSS of the referred-to comment?  There are probably a couple of ways to do this.

The first step is going to be to make sure that you have a way to select that particular DOM element once the page loads.  For that, in your commentItem template, you might do something like this:

```
<template name='commentItem'>
  <div class='commentItem' id='comment-{{_id}}'>
    ....
  </div>
</template>
```

If you're using `iron:router`, a quick and easy way (but not a particularly robust way) to do this would be to manually redirect to the commentList page, then perform your manipulation as part of the event handler once the page has rendered:

```
Template.notification.events({
  'click a':function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // don't let this take you anywhere
    var commentTemplate = this.commentId;
    Router.go($(event.currentTarget).attr('href'));
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $('#comment-' + commentTemplate).addClass('whatever-class-you-want');
    }, 500); // need to wait for the page to render first -- this is probably not a robust method
  }
});
```

A more robust option, which has the added benefit of persisting on page refresh, might be to add an optional `referrer` parameter to the URL (i.e., have the link be something like `<a href="{{pathFor commentsPage query='referrer=[comment _id]'}}">...</a>`, where [comment _id] is replaced by the _id of the comment in question), then in your commentList template, once your page has rendered, you can see if there's a referrer, and if there is, change the CSS:

```
Template.commentList.rendered = function() { 
  var referrer = Router.current().params.query.referrer;
  if (referrer) { 
    $('#comment-' + referrer).addClass('whatever-class-you-want');
  }
}
```

Comment: You are my savior and a genius and I just learned a lot from this. The only question is, when I use the first method, it won't add the class to the #id. I'd have to click on the notification again to add class.

Comment: I added a setTimeout to the last line of the first method. But I don't know if this is a good way to do this.

Comment: Right now I have a helper for href to return `Router.routes.postPage.path({_id: this.postId});`. I want to try using the second method. Since then it will show the notification highlight even when refreshed. And I wouldnt have to use setTimeout. How would I pass this `Router.routes.postPage.path({_id: this.postId});` data in helpers for `pathFor`?

Comment: `<a href="{{pathFor 'postPage' _id=this.postId query='referrer=[comment _id]'}}">` I have this. It gets me to the correct page. (yay!) the url returns `http://localhost:3000/posts/YwhbHP6d4gkv785KN?referrer=[comment%20_id]` . But this is the comment id returns `id =comment-a8dF86TG37pcm8nAu`

Comment: Got it by using `hash` instead of `query` or `referrer`

Comment: @SangYooKim I think you're right that the first method needs to wait for the page to render before it adds the class, which means you have to uset setTimeout, which is unreliable.  
I should have been more clear in the second point -- by '[comment _id]' I meant to take whatever the _id of the comment is and use it there, so the end result when displayed on the page would look like `http://localhost:3000/posts/YwhbHP6d4gkv785KN?referrer=AbCdEfGhIJkLmNoPq`, but you could do it with a hash instead of query also.

Comment: I've been playing around with this and I can't thank you enough. I was just wondering what the difference would be with referrer and hash?

Comment: Hashes typically refer to a portion of the larger document provided by the URL; e.g., to scroll to an anchor: `http://myapp.com/#myanchor`.  A parameter (e.g., `?referrer=`), on the other hand, is typically used when you have to pull something out of a database or otherwise display different information on a page; roughly speaking in Meteor terms it specifies a data context for your page in some fashion.

You can read more about hashes here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier
https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267136

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You have helped me a lot! I wish I could upvote your answer more than once.